# ClassNotFoundException: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException

Tags: jmeter-plugins

I have downloaded" "RPC_Load_Test.jmx" the example file from https://github.com/jlavallee/JMeter-Rabbit-AMQP
when I launch from JMeter, i am getting below error. Can anyone help in this regard.

Cause:
ClassNotFoundException: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException

Detail:com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException:

Answer (score 0):

The error statest that you need to have [`com.rabbitmq.amqp-client`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rabbitmq/amqp-client) library in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) so either copy the .jar from "lib" folder of your project or download it from Maven Central and drop to JMeter's "lib" folder

JMeter restart will be required to pick the .jar up

Also the project [assumes quite an old JMeter version - 2.11](https://github.com/jlavallee/JMeter-Rabbit-AMQP/blob/master/ivy.xml#L19) and according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so I would recommend re-building it linked with the latest [JMeter 5.4.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-4-1-released-td5739226.html) just in case.